# How to custom value of upload form in Antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am creating a Upload Form using Ant Design to upload some image but had some trouble. I just want to get the response object from APIs backend instead of full object properties (see this in the image below).

[image]

I just need clean result which i got it from **response field** like this:

```
[{
   apiVersion: '1.0',   
   data: {...}
}]
```

My full sample code:

```
    const [ fileList, setFileList ] = useState([]);

    const normFile = (e) => {
        if (Array.isArray(e)) {
            return e;
        }
        return e && e.fileList;
    }

    const handleFileChange = ({ fileList }) => {
       setFileList(fileList);
    }   

    const handleFormFinish = (values) => {
        console.log(values)
        // i just want to get simple result:
        // [{ apiVersion: '1.0', data: {...} }]
    }

    return (

      <Form
        form={form}
        layout="vertical"
        onFinish={handleFormFinish}
      >
        <Form.Item
            label="Upload"
            name="upload_image"
            valuePropName="fileList"
            getValueFromEvent={normFile}              
            rules={[
                {
                    required: true, 
                    message: 'Please choose an image!' 
                }
            ]}          
        >

            <Upload
                action="http://localhost:5000/api/upload"
                listType="picture-card"
                fileList={fileList}
                onChange={handleFileChange}
                name="image"
                accept="image/*"
            >
                <CameraOutlined className="icon-uploader"/>
            </Upload>

        </Form.Item>
     )
```

Comment: Can't you just `map` it out from `values`?

Comment: `const responses = values.map(v => v.response)` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @VishnuSajeev I'm not sure about this way but it will be inconvenient if there are more upload items

Comment: Do we have any other solution?